# Why does C++11 not support declaring extern "C" on a static member function?

Tags: c++, c, static, c++11, extern

Provided that I have a C library containing a function declared as `void g(void (*callback)());` The following code is elegant yet illegal:

```
struct A
{
    // error C2159: more than one storage class specified (VC++ Nov 2012 CTP)
    static extern "C" void callback()
    {}
};

g(A::callback);
```

Why does C++11 not support this?

Comment: Have you tried _without_ the `extern "C"`?

Comment: If without extern "C", the function name will be mangled and the linking will fail.

Comment: what link error? it compiles on gcc4.7.2

Comment: @xmllmx: Are you sure linking will fail?

Comment: @xmllmx If `g` expects an `extern "C" void (*)()`, then `g(&A::callback)` is illegal, and requires a compiler diagnostic.  A lot of compilers don't enforce this, however (and are thus broken in this respect).

Comment: error C2159: more than one storage class specified (VC++ Nov 2012 CTP)

Comment: But the C function doesn't call the callback _by name_, it only sees a _pointer_. So the name mangling is a non-issue. Please _try_ before you ask.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Name mangling _isn't_ the issue.  Calling conventions are.  Name mangling is part of the calling conventions, but it isn't all of them.  I've actually used a compiler where C and C++ used different calling conventions (caller cleaned up the stack in C, callee in C++).

Comment: doesn't seem to be a good fit for a SO question, the answer can only be guessed.

Comment: @claptrap no we have several committee members on SO and we have all the pre and postmailings of the committee meetings publicly available. hence there is no need to guess.

Comment: For the record, G++ ignores language linkage of function types, but that's a [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2316). Clang++ also ignores them, presumably for G++ compatibility.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page"

Answer (score 22):

This is a particularly confusing topic to wade into. Let's attack §7.5 "Linkage specifications" [dcl.link].

> 1) All function types, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage have a *language linkage*.

Note that the property of language linkage applies to two completely different kinds of entities: *types* and *names*.

A function has a generally-invisible bit of information in its type which identifies which ABI it conforms to: C calling conventions, Pascal, Fortran, all might be specified to use the stack in different ways, so calling them through a pointer requires knowing the invisible language-tag.

The *name* of a variable or function from another language can be accessed syntactically through C++, or from the other language referring to a C++ declaration. But not every language can match up with C++'s naming scheme and OO model. So interfaces in this scheme don't include classes.

Because these things are managed separately, it's possible to have something with different linkage in its type (calling conventions) and its name (linker symbol).

> 4) Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the innermost one determines the language
>   linkage. A linkage specification does not establish a scope. A *linkage-specification* shall occur only in namespace scope (3.3). In a *linkage-specification*, the specified language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage declared within the *linkage-specification.* A C language linkage is ignored in determining the language linkage of the names of class members and the function type of class member functions.

The `extern "C" {}` affects all function declarations, including pointers and references, except member functions. Since a function may only be defined in a namespace or as a member, C functions can only be defined at namespace scope.

The standard gives an example here:

```
extern "C" typedef void FUNC_c();

class C {
   // the name of the function mf1 and the member 
   // function’s type have C++ language linkage; the 
   // parameter has type pointer to C function
   void mf1(FUNC_c*);

   // the name of the function mf2 and the member
   // function’s type have C++ language linkage
   FUNC_c mf2;

   // the name of the data member q has C++ language
   // linkage and the data member’s type is pointer to
   // C function
   static FUNC_c* q;
};
```

You can emulate the behavior you want using a `typedef`, though. From another example in §7.5/4,

```
extern "C" typedef void FUNC();

// the name f2 has C++ language linkage and the 
// function’s type has C language linkage
FUNC f2;
```

Combining these examples with yours, you can have

```
extern "C" typedef void callback_t();

callback_t A_callback; // declare function with C++ name and C type

struct A
{
    static callback_t &callback; // not a member function
};

// in source file:

// definition matches semantics of declaration, although not syntax
void A_callback() { ... }

// define static member reference
callback_t &A::callback = A_callback;

g(A::callback); // call syntax is emulated
```

In practice, it seldom makes a difference. C and C++ use compatible calling conventions on most platforms (see Jonathan Wakely's comments on this page for exceptions), as long as you don't try to pass or return a non-POD C++ class type. This is a less-implemented feature of C++, due to the confusing overloading of terms and conceptual distinctions ranging from subtle to academic.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you let the compiler determine the function type outside of the class body to have C language linkage, and then use that type todclare the function: `extern "C" typedef void x(); struct A { static x f; };`. Does the spec define the behavior of this? i am currently on a hurry and cant check.

Comment: The same rule does apply to static member functions, but that wouldn't give `mf3` C language linkage. Note that it's the _parameter_ of `mf2` that has C language linkage, not the type of `mf2` itself. i.e. a static member function of a class inside an `extern "C"` block still has C++ language linkage.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, I've tried that before, EDG (which does respect language linkage of functions) ignores the language linkage of the typedef when declaring the member function, i.e. `f` is `extern "C++"` just as though it had been declared normally.

Comment: Solaris CC 5.9 (which warns about language linkage mismatches but still compiles them) agrees with EDG, the static member function does not get C language linkage however it's declared.  (My first test was wrong, so I thought it didn't, but I fixed it)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for bringing this back to my attention. I rushed this answer and overlooked part of a sentence. Those compilers are indeed compliant and the gist of this answer is wrong.

Comment: disappointing that I also can't _declare_ a _friend_ function as `extern "C"` within the class (I can declare the `extern "C"` function outside the class and declare it to be a friend, but I can't do it without the external (and visible) decl.)

Answer (score 3):

First, the function declaration *is* legal.  The `extern "C"`,
however, is ignored for class members, so if `g` expects an
`extern "C" void (*)()`, you can't pass it `callback`.

As to the why of this, I suspect that originally, it was mainly 
a question of orthogonality: it makes no sense for a class
member function to be `extern "C"` in general, and orthogonality
(or simply no one considered the case of static members) means
that this applies to static member functions as well, although
allowing them to be `extern "C"` would have been useful.  Today
(i.e. C++11), it would be problematic to change the rule,
because it could break existing code.  IMHO, the change would
be acceptable, because the amount of code it would break is
probably very small, and the breakage results in a compile time
error—not a change in runtime semantics—so is easily
detected and fixed.  Still, as far as I know, no one made
a proposal to change this, so it didn't get changed.

Comment: `extern "C"` is illegal for class members. 7.1.1/6: *The extern specifier can be applied only to the names of variables and functions. The extern specifier cannot be used in the declaration of class members or function parameters.* It has been illegal since C++98 too.

Comment: @Jon I was basing my statement on §7.5/4: "A C language linkage is ignored in determining the language linkage of the names of class
members and the function type of class member functions." And 
§7.1.1/6 doesn't say anything about linkage specifiers; §7.1.1
is entirely about storage class specifiers, not linkage
specifiers.

Comment: @Jon No need to.  The standard is anything but obvious in a lot of cases.

Comment: However, 7.5/4 also says "A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope" -- doesn't that prohibit its usage inside a class declaration?

Comment: @JamesKanze No, `extern "C"` is only allowed at namespace scope. 7.5/4: "A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope (3.3)" Your quote from same paragraph is referring to when a class appears inside an `extern "C" { }` block.

Comment: @Jon That would seem to cover it, yes.  (It makes sense.  If the specification is going to be ignored, it makes sense to forbid it.)  I was sure I'd seen some examples with `extern "C" static ...` in a class, but apparently, I was mistaken (or was dealing with a compiler error).

Comment: @Potatoswatter When the class is encompased in an `extern "C" { }`, or when the function type is defined by a typedef which contains an `extern "C"`.  The latter is interesting, because it allows defining a member function which takes a pointer to an `extern "C"` function.

Comment: i think the latter may also makes it possible to give the function itself a type that has c language linkage. the quote of the comment above only says that for member functions, a linkage specification is ignored for determining the function type. however if you typedef the type outside, the type is already determined. the spec does not say that it changes the function type after the fact used by the declaration.

Comment: however it happens to be not clear whether "determining" appertains to only the name or also the function type. because if the text is to be interpreted as "... ignored in the function type ..." then you cant do the typedef trickery either.