# C delegate to C++

Tags: c++, delegates

I have a small problem using a library that gets images from a CMOS camera.
The library permits to use a stream functionality and I have three access point to set (three delegates) for when I get an image, when an image is dropped and when there is an error.

```
typedef void(* StreamCallbackPtr)( IMAGE *image );
typedef void(* StreamErrorCallbackPtr)();
typedef void(* StreamFrameDroppedCallbackPtr)();

int Stream_Start( DEVICE device, IMAGEFORMAT format, StreamCallbackPtr  stream_callback, StreamFrameDroppedCallbackPtr  f_dropped_callback, StreamErrorCallbackPtr  error_callback );
```

I enter a StreamCallbackPtr as soon as an image is ready on the camera, but keep in mind that I do not have any ways of changing the library code.

And here is the question: How do I plug my own delegate in C++ ?
Lets say I use this stream functionality inside a class, I know that I have at least two options; the wrapper, and global variables. The first one seems compromised since I cannot pass anything else than an `IMAGE`, and I want to avoid using global variables (it would be static members in this case).

Any ideas ?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395192/why-does-c11-not-support-declaring-extern-c-on-a-static-member-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a static member function as the `StreamCallbackPtr` which then can access a private static reference or list of references to the C++ delegates which wish to receive the message.

That way you have hidden most of the details as private to the class.

The code below is pseudo-C++ (I haven't checked it properly) but it should give you the idea of what I am suggesting.

```
class Delegate
{
protected:
    void Callback( IMAGE *image ) = 0;
    void Error() = 0;
    void FrameDropped() = 0;

public:
    static void SetDelegate(Delegate* d) { delegateInstance = d; }   

    static void StaticCallback( IMAGE *image)
    {   
        // Invoke the delegate instance
        if (delegateInstance != nullptr) delegateInstance->Callback(); 
    }   
    // Same for the others...

private:
    static Delegate* delegateInstance = nullptr;
};

class MyClass : public Delegate
{
protected:
    void Callback( IMAGE *image )
    {   
        // Now the callback is in a delegate instance
    }   
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass mc; 
    Delegate::SetDelegate(&mc);

    StreamCallbackPtr scp = &Delegate::StaticCallback;
    // Register the other static callbacks...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I get it, but would you have an example ? And then the C++ delegates would have to be static...

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried that already, but thanks again. But is there any way of not having a static delegate ?

Comment: You just don't forward the call on to the instance. I read your post again, was my example the wrapper? If so why is that compromised?

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is probably the best workaround... But there is still something that is missing: how to best hide the class delegate in `MyClass`? Do I create a nested class (inside `MyClass`) `Delegate` and another nested class `DelegateHelper` (who inherits from `Delegate`) that holds the delegate methods and call the method from `MyClass` itself ?

Comment: If you want to hide it that much I would just have the static methods, the delegate methods they call and the static instance reference in `MyClass` directly.